# Adding _concat to numbers to create number ranges - am I mad?

Tags: lua, numbers, range, concatenation, metatable

Just as a random experiment I'm considering adding a `__concat()` metamethod to the `number` metatable (usually a new metatable as numbers don't seem to have metatables by default?).

The idea is that I could do something like `3..5` and get back `3, 4, 5`.

I could then have a function `foo(tbl, ...)` that does something with multiple indexes on a table and call it like `foo(tbl, 3..5)`.

Am I barking mad or does this seem like a viable thing to do?

Rough draft of code (not tested yet):

```
-- get existing metatable if there is one
local m = getmetatable( 0 ) or {};

-- define our concat method
m.__concat = function( left, right )
    -- note: lua may pre-coerce numbers to strings?
    -- http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2006-12/msg00482.html
    local l, r = tonumber(left), tonumber(right);

    if not l or not r then -- string concat
        return tostring(left)..tostring(right);

    else -- create number range
        if l > r then l, r = r, l end; -- smallest num first?
        local t = {};
        for i = l, r do t[#t+1] = i end;
        return (table.unpack or unpack)(t);

    end
end

-- set the metatable
setmetatable( 0, m );
```

Additional question: Is there any way for me to populate a `...` value by value (to remove the need for a table & unpack in the example above)?

Comment: In Lua numbers are always coercible to a string, so evaluation of expression `3 .. 5` would never involve a metamethod `__concat`,  `3 .. 5` will always be equal to string `35`.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff unless you define `LUA_NOCVTN2S` when you compile lua.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea can be implemented using `__call` metamethod:

```
local mt = debug.getmetatable(0) or {}
mt.__call = function(a,b)  -- a, b - positive integer numbers
   return (('0'):rep(a-1)..('1'):rep(b-a+1)):match(('()1'):rep(b-a+1))
end
debug.setmetatable(0, mt)

-- Example:
print((3)(5))  -->  3  4  5
```

Comment: That's insane but I like it :) I also have absolutely no idea how it works. Where are the numbers being called to trigger `__call()`? What is this witchcraft before me?!

Comment: Ah... (3)(5) like (obj)( ... )

Now if I could just make sense of the `return` line...

Comment: Hrm, `print((0)(5))` --> `1 2 3 4 5 6`

Comment: Yes, it works only for positive integer numbers.  You can rewrite the function to properly handle arbitrary number ranges.